# How to specify custom health check registry in spring boot (application.yml)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to inject a custom `com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheckRegistry`in a spring boot application using the property `spring.datasource.hikari.health-check-registry` in application.yml ?  And how to do that?

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb;failoverPatner=
    username: db_user
    password: db_pass
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
      health-check-registry: ???????
    jmx-enabled: true
```

Comment: you read this?https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-HealthChecks

Comment: or this: https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/database-connection-pooling-in-java-with-hikaricp

Comment: yes. these docs are about hikari pool, but question is about spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

With healthCheckRegistry and healthCheckProperties, you can register HealthCheck and test it after execution, for example by calling the url.
Sample:

```
  HealthCheckRegistry healthCheckRegistry = new HealthCheckRegistry();
  healthCheckRegistry.register("Database", new DatabaseHealthCheck());
```

and run it:

```
  healthCheckRegistry.runHealthCheck("database");
```

Or you can unregister it:

```
  healthCheckRegistry.unregister("database");
```

[For more review](https://www.baeldung.com/dropwizard-metrics)